# Proverbs 15:23 - what does "a word in season" mean?

Tags: proverbs

Proverbs 15:23

> To make an apt answer is a joy to a man,
>
> and a word in season, how good it is!

So "a word in season" like a word that is remembered in seasons, like season in a year?

Comment: **Fitly Spoken** A similar proverb highlights the need to speak at the right time for the ultimate in efficiency.  _A word fitly (aptly) spoken is like apples of gold in a silver setting (silver bowl)_. (Proverbs 25:11)  A word at the right timing would be fitly (aptly) spoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hebrew poetry (and other forms of poetry from the same region), parallelism is an important concept (much more than rhythm, rhyme, or other things important in English poetry). In Hebrew we usually have bicola, that is pairs of verses that are paralleled. We then talk about the A-colon and the B-colon (similarly, [A-words and B-words](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/29516/2672)). The A-colon often contains relatively common words. The B-colon more or less repeats the A-colon, but can make it more specific or use more sophisticated words (for example words that have an ancient aire about them).

In the Hebrew we have the B-colon:

> וְדָבָר בְּעִתֹּו מַה־טֹּֽוב
>   ... and word in its time - how good

In this case, an "apt answer" and a "word in its time" mean more or less the same thing. The verse is best read in context of vv. 20–23. As Waltke (The Book of Proverbs, Chapters 1–15) notes (p. 663):

> Parents have joy when their children receive their good counsel (v. 20), and wise adults have joy in accepting ethical counsel (vv. 22–23) and in giving it (v. 23).

He also comments on the expression "it its time":

> *In its time* (*b<sup>e</sup>`ittô*; see 5:19) refers to an appropriate time conceived of as an opportunity (L. J. Coppes, TWOT, 2:680, s.v. *'ēt*).

Comment: so "a word in season" = "word in its time", like a word that said at the right moment/time?

Comment: @123iamking exactly.

Comment: An apt and timely answer, Keelan.

Comment: We used to eat vegetables that were "in season". Now you can buy them all year round in a supermarket, so people no longer understand this English idiom.

Answer (score 1):

This is referring to a right time and a wrong time for sharing a word to someone. This is about patience in counselling another. I have jumped to share something without waiting on the leading of the Spirit and it seemed to corrupt what I was saying because the person was not in the right "season" to hear thise words.

Answer (score 0):

It’s like eating a properly seasoned meal, not too salty and not overly seasoned but seasoned to your taste! It’s like tasting a piece of fruit i.e. watermelon  that is cold on a hot day and sugar sweet! Oh “how sweet it is” to receive a word from the scriptures, a friend, a relative a text,  the radio, or even a complete stranger! When you are the one giving it out you’ll come to know automatically by the immediate response of the receiver! They will embrace it and you will thank God for giving it to you to share!

First, you received it and because it was so delicious (oh taste and see…) you being at the Master's table want to share it! You are contagious with this now and want to see that same joy you have transformed to others to others! Now read the word, God's always speaking, He wants us to be obedient and simply share it with someone! This is a first for me, making a comment, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).